Is insurance required to pay for urgent care?
In the United States of America, are all urgent care's covered by insurance? Is there a difference between going to Urgent Care and the Emergency Room?
Trying to help a friend get something looked at but was uncertain how insurance may play a role.

This is probably more of a personal finance question that would be on topic over on money.stackexchange.  In general, insurance will cover visits to urgent care but some urgent care locations may be in network and others may be out of network so the amount of coverage may be (very) different.

Obligatory, but unfortunate, scam warning: if this is an "internet friend", who "needs to go to Urgent Care but their insurance won't cover it", and is asking if you can help them... be very careful.

@JustinCave emergency care is considered in-network regardless of provider.

@littleadv - But urgent care is designed for things that need urgent attention but are not emergencies so in- and out-of-network is a consideration.

Right, so it really depends on the actual situation. Some times people go to urgent care for actual emergencies, other times - not really.

The person the friend should be asking is the health plan's 24/7 nurse hotline, not a friend or random people on the Internet.

@user71659 Legal context is appropriate and helps to understand the stakes, especially if you aren't familiar with the U.S. healthcare system.


In the United States of America, are all urgent care's covered by
insurance?

No.
This is a determination for the insurance company and the urgent care provider to reach mutually. The urgent care is not required to accept all insurance policies, nor is it required to accept uninsured patients.
For example, my health insurance policy covers some urgent care facilities that are in its network, but it does not cover out of network urgent care facilities. And, the in network ERs that my health insurance covers generally don't serve people who don't have insurance (although most urgent care facilities are happy to treat someone on a cash payment basis).

Is there a difference between going to Urgent Care and the Emergency
Room?

Yes.
The Emergency Medical Treatment and Labor Act of 1986 (EMTALA), requires emergency rooms (ERs) to treat anyone presented to them seeking treatment until their condition is stabilized, whether or not they can afford to pay. ERs are required to have an M.D. in essentially every sub-speciality of medicine that could present in that ER on call. And, the Affordable Care Act (ACA a.k.a. Obamacare) requires that insurance policies qualified for tax subsidies under the act cover emergency care. See 42 CFR 438.114.
ERs are much, much more expensive than urgent care facilities. This is in part, because they have to have every specialty on call, in part because they are often affiliated with hospitals which charge more than doctor's offices for the same services, in part because they have lots of slack time, and in part, because mandatory treatment of patients means that they have lots of bad debt that has to be covered with paying patients.
It also takes a state government "certificate of necessity", which is discretionary and not lightly given, to open up a new ER. This limits the supply of ERs which, of course, drives up their prices.
None of the requirements particular to ERs in the United States apply (at least under federal law) to urgent care facilities, which from a regulatory perspective are basically just doctor's offices with extended hours that hold themselves out as handling matters promptly and without an appointment, but make clear that they are not ERs.
While urgent care facilities are not different from other doctor's offices from a regulatory perspective for the most part, insurance companies commonly do have a special co-pay or deductible for urgent care that creates an incentive to go to an urgent care rather than an ER when appropriate, but a rate that is higher than a normal, in network, doctor visit (which, since it can be scheduled in advance, thus, not requiring the doctor to have as much slack time as an urgent care facility, is cheaper).
There is a whole elaborate classification of conditions that people are expected to know, about what symptoms and conditions require ER care, what urgent care is appropriate for, and what calls for a normal doctor or nurse visit.
The financial and treatment quality consequences for a patient getting it wrong can be severe. If you go to an urgent care facility when you need an ER, you could die because they aren't equipped to handle your emergency. If you go to an ER when you only needed urgent care, you could be headed for a medical debt driven bankruptcy because the cost of ER treatment for something that could be treated in an urgent care facility is often 100x as high (e.g. $10,000 v. $100). Going to an urgent care when an ordinary doctor's visit on a non-urgent basis was available could easily cost 1.5x to 3x as much as the scheduled doctor's appointment (e.g. $150-$300 v. $100).
Related Issues
A specialty "trauma center" or "stroke center", for example, is just one kind of ER for legal and regulatory and insurance coverage purposes.
Even if your insurance has a flat co-pay or maximum patient responsibility for an ER visit, or an urgent care visit, or a doctor's office visit, this price typically won't include diagnostic tests, treatment materials (e.g. medicines or medical devices), or an after visit stay in a hospital for even a single night.
A closely related issue is that some doctors are closely affiliated with hospitals, and when performing services at a hospital affiliated facility charge a much higher rate than at a private, stand alone, doctor's office for the same treatment.
Footnote Re International Comparisons
Many, if not most, countries do not make a clear distinction between emergency rooms and urgent care facilities, with the same facility often handling both kinds of conditions.
This is largely of product of the way national health care bureaucracies are organized.
In a country with universal health care (which is most non-U.S. countries), ERs are not packed with people seeking care from this highest cost provider because it is the only provider required to treat them without payment. Instead, all providers get paid for services provided to all patients, and poor patients are as likely as anyone else to get care from a lower cost provider.
Also, in most countries, the minimum standards to operate an ER are not as high, so their ERs don't need to have every available medical speciality available on call.

Every health plan I've been on has a included 24/7 nurse line for you to call up and they tell you where you should go.

@user71659 Which lots of people don't have the presence of mind to use in an emergency, and which isn't available if you don't have health insurance (about 8.2% of Americans do not). There's an editorial cartoon, that I can't locate at the moment, featuring a widow at the grave of a man who died while trying to log into an online web account to get advice.

"There is a whole elaborate classification of conditions that people are expected to know..." "The financial and treatment quality consequences for a patient getting it wrong can be severe." F the scammy US medical system. It is dysfunctional by design. (Thank you for you informative and well-written answer though.)
